# Apache mass virtual host configuration issue

Tags: apache, ssl, dns, vps

I'm brand new to VPS hosting, so bear with me.

I recently purchased a VPS through inmotion hosting. It has Apache, cPanel and WHM installed out of box. I'm not sure if this is important, but at the top right of the WHM root login it shows: CENTOS 7.3 x86_64

I'm working on developing a system where users can sign up with me and be provided with a sub domain like so: theirUsername.mydomain.com. This will point to a directory on my server where their files will be located. People should also be allowed to have a domain name with my nameservers. I need the system to automatically detect their domain name and point it to where their directory is. It's just like if I were to manually log into cPanel and create an addon domain, but I need this process to be automated. I also need the sub domain to remain and I need to be able to install SSL certs for these domains.

My system would be VERY similar to how Squarespace works.

I've read into mass virtual hosting but cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it working or if it would even be what I'm looking for.

I've tried configuring the virtual hosting but have had no luck. Just for testing purposes I was trying a single domain. Here is my code:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # SSL name based virtual hosts are not yet supported, therefore no
    # NameVirtualHost statement here
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/username/www/domain.com" 
    ServerName www.domain.com    
    ServerAlias domain.com
    ErrorLog "/home/username/www/domain.com/error.log" 
    CustomLog "/home/username/www/domain.com/requests.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The log files are making it to that directory but visiting the domain gives me a "This site can’t be reached" error in Chrome.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: First you need to make your domain point to the IP of the server. It's not the case yet if Chrome says it can't even reach a server. Worst case scenario, if your vhost was not working correctly, it would display the default vhost.

Comment: Also, imho, this should be asked on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: The domain is pointed to my server I believe. Because when I create an addon domain with it it works fine.